# Cannot pass react's setState for router's navigate()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, frontend

I have this `products` component:

```
function Products() {
  // react hooks
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // local state
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});
  ...

  return (
   ...
     <button
        onClick={() => navigate('/admin/products/new', { state: { category: selectedCategory, setProducts } })}
        className=" bg-green-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded my-[1rem]"
      >
   ...
  ); 
}
```

and then creating new product:

```
function NewProduct() {
  // react hooks
  const location = useLocation();
  const { category, setProducts } = location?.state;
  ...
  
   async function onSave() {
    console.log("Product saved:", { image, title, description, price });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('category', category);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('image', image);

    const res = await ctx.axios.post("/products", formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
    });
    const p = res.data;
    setProducts(prev => prev[category].push({
      hash: p.uuid,
      imgFilename: p.imgFilename,
      title: p.title,
      description: p.description,
      price: p.price
    }));
    navigate('/admin/products')
  }
  ...
}
```

but when I go to `/admin/products/new` (`NewProduct.js` component), I got:

```
BoundFunctionObject object could not be cloned
```

and the reason is

```
    onClick={() => navigate('/admin/products/new', { state: { category: selectedCategory, setProducts } })}
```

sending `setProducts` reacts state via `navigate()`, but I needed to set products when new one is created of course. How to solve it?

Comment: I was thinking about using useContext global context for the `setProducts` state method, for that does not feel right, using context just for state management. How to simply use the router's navigate for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass JSON serializable values in route state. Trying to pass the React state updater function will nullify the passed route state.

A React context makes sense here, and a simple implementation would be to create a layout route that wraps the routes that you want to work with this `products` state.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductsLayout = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

  return <Outlet context={{ products, setProducts }} />;
};
```

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path="/admin/products" element={<ProductsLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Products />} />
    <Route path="new" element={< NewProduct />} />
    ...
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```

The components shall use the `useOutletContext` hook to access the provided `Outlet` context value.

```
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

function Products() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { products } = useOutletContext();

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <button
      onClick={() => navigate(
        'new', // <-- "/admin/products/new"
        { state: { category: selectedCategory } }
      )}
      ...
    >
      ...
    </button>
    ...
  ); 
}
```

Additionally, please ensure you are using an immutable state update when updating the `products` state value. Shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updates into ***new*** object references. You may also want to surround your asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` so any thrown errors or Promise rejections and be caught and possibly handled.

```
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

function NewProduct() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { setProducts } = useOutletContext();

  const { category } = location.state ?? {};
  ...
  
  async function onSave() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('category', category);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('image', image);

    try {
      const { data } = await ctx.axios.post("/products", formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      });

      const {
        description,
        imgFilename,
        price,
        title,
        uuid: hash,
      } = data;

      const newProduct = {
        hash,
        imgFilename,
        title,
        description,
        price
      };

      setProducts(products => ({ // <-- new object reference
        ...products              // <-- shallow copy current state
        [category]: products[category]
          .concat(newProduct)    // <-- copy & new array reference
      }));
      navigate('/admin/products');
    } catch(error) {
      // handle errors/rejections
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

If more than just these `"/admin/products/*"` routes need this `products` state then you can lift the state higher and provide it via a regular React Context provider.